# Multiple insert with radio groups

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form which has three parts; level 1, level 2 and level 3.  Each of these parts contain four text areas and a radio group, with the radio buttons next to each text area:

```
  <form action="" method="post" name="form" id="form" onSubmit="return validate();">
    <table width="123%" border="0" cellpadding="5">
      <th colspan="6">
        <div align="center"><strong>Level 1</strong></div>      </th>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway</strong></td>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Blocking or Accepting Comment</strong></td>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Appropriate</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="26%" valign="top"><strong>Pathway 1:</strong> No action - See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l1_p1_comment" id="l1_p1_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="18%" valign="top"><p>
            <input type="radio" name="l1_allowed" value="1" id="l1_allowed_0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 2:</strong> See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l1_p2_comment" id="l1_p2_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l1_allowed" value="1" id="l1_allowed_1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 3:</strong> Refer to ED</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l1_p3_comment" id="l1_p3_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l1_allowed" value="1" id="l1_allowed_2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 4:</strong> Refer to Specialist</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l1_p4_comment" id="l1_p4_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l1_allowed" value="1" id="l1_allowed_3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    <th colspan="6">
        <div align="center"><strong>Level 2</strong></div>      </th>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway</strong></td>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Blocking or Accepting Comment</strong></td>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Appropriate</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="26%" valign="top"><strong>Pathway 1:</strong> No action - See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l2_p1_comment" id="l2_p1_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="18%" valign="top"><p>
            <input type="radio" name="l2_allowed" value="1" id="l2_allowed_0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 2:</strong> See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l2_p2_comment" id="l2_p2_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l2_allowed" value="1" id="l2_allowed_1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 3:</strong> Refer to ED</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l2_p3_comment" id="l2_p3_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l2_allowed" value="1" id="l2_allowed_2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 4:</strong> Refer to Specialist</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l2_p4_comment" id="l2_p4_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l2_allowed" value="1" id="l2_allowed_3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2">&nbsp;</td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
          <th colspan="6">
        <div align="center"><strong>Level 3</strong></div>      </th>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway</strong></td>
        <td colspan="2"><strong>Blocking or Accepting Comment</strong></td>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Appropriate</strong></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="26%" valign="top"><strong>Pathway 1:</strong> No action - See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l3_p1_comment" id="l3_p1_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td width="18%" valign="top"><p>
            <input type="radio" name="l3_allowed" value="1" id="l3_allowed_0" />
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 2:</strong> See again</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l3_p2_comment" id="l3_p2_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l3_allowed" value="1" id="l3_allowed_1" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 3:</strong> Refer to ED</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l3_p3_comment" id="l3_p3_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l3_allowed" value="1" id="l3_allowed_2" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td valign="top"><strong>Pathway 4:</strong> Refer to Specialist</td>
        <td colspan="2"><div class="required">
            <textarea name="l3_p4_comment" id="l3_p4_comment" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea>
          </div></td>
        <td valign="top"><input type="radio" name="l3_allowed" value="1" id="l3_allowed_3" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="Create Pathways for All Levels" /></td>
        <td>&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
```

On submit, there is a multiple insert:

```
$l1_p1_comment = $_POST['l1_p1_comment'];
$l1_p2_comment = $_POST['l1_p2_comment'];
$l1_p3_comment = $_POST['l1_p3_comment'];
$l1_p4_comment = $_POST['l1_p4_comment'];

$l2_p1_comment = $_POST['l2_p1_comment'];
$l2_p2_comment = $_POST['l2_p2_comment'];
$l2_p3_comment = $_POST['l2_p3_comment'];
$l2_p4_comment = $_POST['l2_p4_comment'];

$l3_p1_comment = $_POST['l3_p1_comment'];
$l3_p2_comment = $_POST['l3_p2_comment'];
$l3_p3_comment = $_POST['l3_p3_comment'];
$l3_p4_comment = $_POST['l3_p4_comment'];

$l1_allowed = $_POST['l1_allowed'];
$l2_allowed = $_POST['l2_allowed'];
$l3_allowed = $_POST['l3_allowed'];

if(isset($_POST['submit'])){ 

$query = 
"INSERT INTO pathway 
(pathway_pk, case_fk, level, pathway_allowed, comment, created, created_by) 
VALUES 
('', '$case_fk', '1', '$l1_allowed', '$l1_p1_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '1', '$l1_allowed', '$l1_p2_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'),
('', '$case_fk', '1', '$l1_allowed', '$l1_p3_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '1', '$l1_allowed', '$l1_p4_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'),
('', '$case_fk', '2', '$l2_allowed', '$l2_p1_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '2', '$l2_allowed', '$l2_p2_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'),
('', '$case_fk', '2', '$l2_allowed', '$l2_p3_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '2', '$l2_allowed', '$l2_p4_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'),
('', '$case_fk', '3', '$l3_allowed', '$l3_p1_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '3', '$l3_allowed', '$l3_p2_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'),
('', '$case_fk', '3', '$l3_allowed', '$l3_p3_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk'), 
('', '$case_fk', '3', '$l3_allowed', '$l3_p4_comment', NOW(), '$author_pk')
";
$result = mysql_query($query, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
```

Now, I want to have the radio groups for each of three parts (level 1, level 2 and level3) submit the value '1' (ie allowed) for a selected radio and the other radios in each of the groups submit '0' from:

```
$l1_allowed = $_POST['l1_allowed'];
$l2_allowed = $_POST['l2_allowed'];
$l3_allowed = $_POST['l3_allowed'];
```

Any advice on how I can do this?

Answer (score 0):

First, [escape your inputs correctly](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php).

Then put your code to handle the form's data into a separate page, like submit_action.php.
And try to avoid using `if(isset($_POST['submit'])){`. Instead:

```
if(isset($_POST['input1'])) {
$input1 = ($_POST['input1']);   
} else {
$input1 = "None";
}
if(isset($_POST['input2'])) {
$input1 = ($_POST['input2']);   
} else {
$input1 = "None";
}

<form action="submit_action.php" method="post" name="aFormName" id="form">
```

Then, in your INSERT:

```
$query="INSERT INTO $tbl_name(col1, col2)VALUES('$input1', '$input2')";
```

And you are pointing onsubmit to what, anyways? I see no page link in your question. What is validate()?

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't answer my question.  BTW, the form submits to the current page...no problem doing the inserts, just need advice as to how to handle the radio goups on the multiple inserts...  validate() is a js scipt to validate the form...not include in the above code as not relevant.

Answer (score 0):

OK, I decided this was too difficult with multiple inserts, so split the three areas into seperate forms and used:

```
$l1_allowed = intval($_POST['l1_allowed']);
$l2_allowed = intval($_POST['l2_allowed']);
$l3_allowed = intval($_POST['l3_allowed']);


if(isset($_POST['pathways_level_1'])){ 

$pathway_comment_l1 = array();

foreach($_POST['comment_l1'] as $comment_l1) {
    $pathway_comment_l1[]= mysql_real_escape_string($comment_l1);
}

for($i=0, $count = count($pathway_comment_l1);$i<$count;$i++) {
    $comment_l1 = $pathway_comment_l1[$i];
    $query_level_1 = sprintf(
        "INSERT INTO pathway (             
           pathway_pk,
           case_fk,
           level,
           pathway_allowed,
           comment
        ) VALUES (
           '',
           '$case_pk',
           '1',
           '%s',
           '$comment_l1')", $l1_allowed === $i ? 'y' : 'n');

       $result_level_1 = mysql_query($query_level_1, $connection) or die(mysql_error());
}
if($result_level_1){
$message = "- The pathways for level 1 have been created.";
}
}
?>
```